# Firebug-like debugger for Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging, firebug

Is there anything like Firebug that you can use within Google Chrome?

Essential features I would like:

- Inspect HTML source (select elements, delete them, etc.)
- check CSS values (the built-in solution is weird, somehow)

Comment: Seeing as though Chrome now supports extensions, can we revisit this as many of the existing answers are now technically incorrect. We should update this answer instead of starting a new one.

Comment: @Nathan Koop: I could be wrong, but I don't think the Chrome extension system is powerful enough to allow for something like Firebug.

Comment: check this link to get the firebug on the browser : https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/

Answer (score 245, accepted):

There is a Firebug-like tool already built into Chrome. Just right click anywhere on a page and choose "Inspect element" from the menu. Chrome has a graphical tool for debugging (like in Firebug), so you can debug JavaScript. It also does CSS inspection well and can even change CSS rendering on the fly.

For more information, see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: ++ This is good enough for troubleshooting Chrome-specific issues. If I want deeper introspection, I can do it with Firebug. Now with IE8's new developer mode, all the major browsers have builtin dev modes. Good times.

Comment: Ah, took me a bit to find it, but the html editing functionality of firebug is there as well, in the same place that you can edit the css, the developer toolbar, double click an element, type, and hit enter, and there you go, html edited.

Comment: The Chrome Developer Tools (ctrl+shift+j) does support Javascript debugging like Firebug. Click on the Scripts tab then on the second icon at the bottom (>=) that has a tooltip of "Show console". From there you can execute Javascript commands like the Firebug console.

Comment: Remember on some linux-based system it doesn't get installed automatically, so you need to install it manually:

sudo apt-get install chromium-browser-inspector

Comment: The current dev build 4.0.xxxx has a set of developer tools. I knew about the inspect elements stuff before but without the "Net" panel it wasn't good enough. But there is now a "resources" panel that seems to be working pretty well and has all the same filters as firebug (scripts, xhr, images, etc). I've been using the Dev build for a week and it seems pretty stable. I just finally set my default browser to chrome - now it's my dev browser too! :)

Comment: This supports http headers under "resources" as well (which is very important for debugging Ajax).

Comment: I like Firebug better than what Chrome offers. But I hate how the inspect element works in Firefox. I wish I didn't need to use two separate browsers to debug...

Comment: ++ if you only use chrome for debugging... / console / inspect element.. Sorry mozilla

Comment: While yes Chrome has the debugger ... it doesn't have the power and ease of use that Firebug has. I find myself going back to Firefox if I need powerful debugging, but still use Chrome as my main browser. :-\

Answer (score 37):

Firebug Lite supports to inspect HTML elements, computed CSS style, and a lot more. Since it's pure JavaScript, it works in many different browsers. Just include the script in your source, or add the bookmarklet to your bookmark bar to include it on any page with a single click.

http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Comment: Great link! Didn't know about IE version

Answer (score 15):

Just adding some talking points as someone who uses Firebug / [Chrome Inspector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_chrome#User_interface) every day:

1. At the time of writing, there's only Google DOM inspector and no it doesn't have all the features of Firebug
2. Inspector is a 'lite' version of Firebug: The interface is not as good IMO, element inspection in both recent versions is now clunky, but Firebug is still better; I find myself trying to find the love for Chrome (since it's a better, faster browser experience), but for development work, it still just sucks for me.
3. Live preview / modification of DOM / CSS is still way better in Firebug; calculated CSS and box model view are better in Firebug;
4. Somehow it's just easier to read/use Firebug maybe because of the ease of navigating, manipulating/modifying the document in several key areas?  Who knows. I'm used to the interface and I think Chrome Inspector is not as good although this is a subjective thing I admit.
5. The Cookies/Net tab are extremely useful to me in Firebug. Maybe Chrome Inspector has this now? Last time I checked it did not, because Chrome updates itself in the background without your intervention (gets your consent by default like all good overlords).
6. Last point: The day that Google Chrome gets a fully-featured Firebug is the day Firefox basically dies for developers because Firefox had 3 years to make Firefox's layout engine [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29) as fast as [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) and they didn't.  Sorry to put it so bluntly but it's the truth.

You see, now everyone wants to move away from Flash in lieu of jQuery motivated by mobile accessibility and interactivity (iPhone, iPad, Android) and JavaScript is 'suddenly' a big deal (that's sarcasm), so that ship has sailed, Firefox. And that makes me sad, as a Mozilla fanperson. Chrome is simply a better browser until Firefox upgrades their JavaScript engine.

Comment: Firefox is going downhill. As of now (2013) chrome devtools are much more powerful than firebug ... and firefox is all focusing their efforts on Firefox OS which is not even close to android frodo .. they didn't even put much effort to make js and rendering faster.

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>F12</kbd>

I love shortkeys

Comment: one guy put ctrl shift j :)

Answer (score 13):

Try this, it's called [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/) and apparently works with the beta version of Chrome.

You can also find it at: 
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/

Comment: This is an official extension for Chrome

Answer (score 9):

You can set this bookmarklet in your "Bookmarks Bar" in order to have Firebug lite always available in Chrome/Chromium browser (put this as the URL):

```
javascript:var firebug=document.createElement('script');firebug.setAttribute('src','http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js');document.body.appendChild(firebug);(function(){if(window.firebug.version){firebug.init();}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee);}})();void(firebug);
```

Answer (score 4):

Or try user scripts: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts

Answer (score 4):

The official Firebug Chrome extension or you can download and package the extension yourself.

https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/

Comment: Just for clarity: this is a link to an firebug lite extension not a firebug extension.

Comment: The previously supplied link was broken. Please update this answer with a new link.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuerify](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc) is the perfect extension to embed jQuery into Chrome Console and is as simple as you can imagine. This extension also indicates if jQuery has been already embedded into a page.

This extension is used to embed jQuery into any page you want. It allows to use jQuery in the console shell (You can invoke Chrome console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>".).

To embed jQuery into the selected tab click on extension button.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it is possible to enable [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts for Google Chrome so maybe there is a way to sort of install Firebug using this method? [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) would also work, but it's just not the same feeling as using the full featured one :(

willshouse.com/2009/05/29/install-greasemonkey-for-chrome-a-better-guide/

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question but, in case you missed it, Chris Pederick's [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) is now available for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>F12</kbd> (only on Linux and Windows)

**OR**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

(<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> if you're on Mac)

Answer (score 3):

Forget everything you all needs this browser independent inspector , dom updater

https://goggles.webmaker.org/en-US

just bookmark and go to any webpage and click that bookmark..

this is actually Mozilla project Goggles , amazing amazing amazing...

Comment: They're shutting it down.

Answer (score 2):

Please try [Firebug Lite for Google Chrome](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chromium on Ubuntu using the nightly ppa, then you should have the `chromium-browser-inspector`