# Debug Resource Scripts with Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net, google-chrome

I found the script file inside the Resources tab and not inside the Script tab and hence, when I search for the particular function inside Script's tab, it doesn't return result as shown at
[How to search all loaded scripts in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145266/how-to-search-all-loaded-scripts-in-chrome-developer-tools)

I want to debug the Resource script file with Chrome Developer Tool, how will I be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't debug a script in the Resources tab, so you have to locate the script by name in the Scripts tab.

Comment: that script is not loaded under Script tab for some reason. It's only under Resource tab. It works fine with Firebug in FF though