# How do I search throughout all of my javascript in Chrome Developer Tools on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On a windows machine, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find a phrase in the javascript rendered on a page using the "Sources" tab of Chrome developer tools.

However, if I use this keyboard combination on a Mac, the entire page becomes full screen. What is the analogous keyboard shortcut on a Mac to search javascript sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search all loaded scripts in Chrome Developer Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145266/how-to-search-all-loaded-scripts-in-chrome-developer-tools).  [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970237/456814): "`Cmd + Option + F` on mac".

Comment: Cmd+Option+F gave me the text "Search" at the bottom of my screen but no visible way to search. If this happens to anyone else, the trick is you need to slide the bottom line up to reveal the actual search box. (This is probably obvious but it took me a long time to figure out.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works.

Comment: That's Cmd+(Opt+F) on mac

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>? I don't have a Mac handy to test this on, but usually the Cmd key on a Mac replaces the Ctrl key in Windows hot keys.

Comment: Cmd + Shift + F is "Enter Presentation Mode" on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Check official Chrome Dev Tools documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts