# Change name of counter Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Help me please.
I have name for my counter Universal Analytics (analytics.js) -  clientTracker, but now I want to change it. 
Everithing will be Ok with it, or some statistic can be ruined?
Old and new statistic will be counted in counter correct?

Old name (I want to change it):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker')
```

New name:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'nonStat')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is the tracker name ([GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#naming_trackers)).  The only consideration when changing the tracker name is this: you need to make sure to update every `ga` command that you want to continue to track.

So, if you change:
`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker')`
to:
`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'nonStat')`

...you'll also need to change:
`ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview')`
to:
`ga('nonStat.send', 'pageview')`

...and all other instances of:
`ga('clientTracker.send', ...`
to:
`ga('nonStat.send', ...`

If yours is more advanced than the typical setup, there may also be other references, such as: `ga.getByName('clientTracker')`.  Make sure these are updated too.

Lastly, check all the platform and third-party integrations you have on your website that might integrate with GA (e.g. a CRM) and make sure they don't rely on the existing tracker name.  (A simple way is to search all code sources for the old tracker name [using Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17273749) on multiple pages of the site, including all form pages.)  Any references need to be updated.

That's it; just make sure you replace all references to the old tracker name. Once you change the tracker name in the `create` command, any other commands still using the old tracker name will stop working.

### But first ...

Think about why you want to change the tracker name.  Typically the only reason to have a custom tracker name is to have multiple trackers on the page.  If you have only one tracker, chances are changing the tracker name is extra effort for no benefit.