# Track down what javascript function sets up a click event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to modify a theme's functionality, but I've ran into a snag.

I need to track down what javascript function is setting up an 'add to cart' button click event, which is using ajax.

This is the page where I am trying to diagnose the issue...

http://www.healthjunkies.com.au/benefits-of-whey-protein/

On the sidebar - when you click a purple add to cart button, it creates a success message that looks all screwed up in the side bar. This is because I copied some of the functionality from another part of the theme, and put it into a sidebar widget.

Now I need to isolate the function that is setting up this call.

I tried using the Chrome developer tools, using the breakpoints and it seems it traces the call between jQuery and some click tracker, I am guessing some analytic plugin.

[image: Chrome developer js trace response]

How do I isolate the function that set the event up in the first place, so I can change the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways:

1.) Use Chrome's **Search Panel** (under Sources) to search for the element that the listener is being registered on (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145266/how-to-search-all-loaded-scripts-in-chrome-developer-tools/7970237#7970237) for guide).

[image]

2.) The **"Event Listeners"** tab under **"Elements"**.

[image]

Comment: The first step I think is what I needed. I was looking for the global script search but couldn't work out how to get it up. I did try the second method, but it only displayed the jQuery functionality that was ready to accept the call.

Comment: It did help Matt, thank you. It is actually one of the woo commerce core files - which I don't want to edit directly. I am just trying to think of a way to work around it. Maybe copy the function that sets it up, assign it to another button class and make it act differently.

Comment: @DaleWoods What are you wanting to do differently from existing functionality (what are you trying to change?)

Comment: When you clicked the add to cart button, an ajax call was made - added the item to the cart - then added a div after the add to cart button saying 'check cart'. I just wanted to remove the part that added the div there. What I did was just force all the buttons to be direct links to the product landing page. I am happy with that. But this was a good lesson is tracing JavaScript functionality - which I will no doubt be able to use in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

View page source, line 923-930:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

    $( '.add_to_cart_button:not(.product_type_variable, .product_type_grouped)' ).click( function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Products', 'Add to Cart', ($(this).data('product_sku')) ? ('SKU: ' + $(this).data('product_sku')) : ('#' + $(this).data('product_id')));
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this is Google analyltics tracking. This is not the ajax call which adds the product to the cart :)

Answer (score 0):

More recent solution is in Chrome > Developer tools > Sources > Event listeners > Mouse > Click

Then browse through the events

[image]