# CKEditor Version 4.5.3 integration with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, ckeditor

Good morning to all,

I am trying to integrate Version 4.5.3 of CKEditor with my ASP.NET application using Web forms.

Basically I am aware that the latest version (Version 4.5.3) does not come with a DLL and thus it is running (As I presume) by scripts.
I've been attempting to somehow get it to work, however I'm stuck.

If anyone could point out a sample code of the basic CKEditor instance using web-forms I'd really appreciate it.

The CKEDITOR documentation offers the following code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However in my webform with the above only the text-area was appearing

Thanks

Comment: Anyone with anything :D ?

Comment: Where is ckeditor.js located in your project? This is where Chrome developer tools come in handy. Check the console tab to see if your getting an error and check to see if the script is actually loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145266/how-to-search-all-loaded-scripts-in-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script
```

patch cann't be like that...

if u installed it from nuget patch is `/scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`

try `<script src="~/scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` or `<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`