# How to access and search code in debugger:///VM* files in Google Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I want to debug scripts which are not loaded via files, meaning they loaded via `eval` or Native code pushed to the browser from iOS/Android.

when I write in the DevTools console `(function() {debugger}())` the browser create fake file like `debugger:///VM132` and you can see it in the debugger breakpoint.

I usually has lots of `debugger:///VM***` "files" code but I can't access them and can't see the list of `debugger:///VM` script anywhere in the DevTools. the Sources panel also not showing any of those.

In addition, I use DevTools search `CMD+option+F` and is not searching inside `debugger:///VM` files.

How can I find those sources?

Answer (score 6):

I notice the option in DevTools Settings under `Sources` -> `Search in anonymous and content scripts`. I get all console scripts, debugger conditional breakpoints, and injected scripts from Native App to JS.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Then you have to use "search", as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970237/3163669