# How to change background color of jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, styles

I am having tough time figure out how to change background color of `jQuery UI Dialog`.

I've seen many reference how to change/remove title bar but not **entire background including those curvy corner.**

Here is my try:

http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/11/

The problem is **.ui-widget-content** only applies to square area within the dialog but not including curvy corner.

I found a class **.ui-corner-all** class hoping it will color the entire background but only half of the dialog is colored. (you can see this in the jsfiddle)

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: add background color at .ui-dialog then it should work.
See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/25/)

Comment: Do I have to do it in inline level? If I define the style in external CSS, the style is not being applied. Looking at firebug, native jquery dialog code overrides the external css

Comment: Oh no I was wrong. My css class selectors were defined wrongly. ".foo .bar" when it should be ".foo.bar" (whitespace)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can use this way

http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/15/

You should set to all class background with use !important.

`.ui-dialog,.ui-widget, .ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all, .foo, .ui-draggable, .ui-resizable {background:yellow !important`}​

Comment: Thanks! I think stackoverflow now has dependency to jsfiddle

Comment: @Paul Probably it doesn't work to was affected by other css. You can review using Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: This has .ui-dialog twice. FWIW, I found this to save the header: .ui-dialog, .ui-dialog, .ui-widget-content, .ui-draggable, .ui-resizable

Comment: "You should set to all class background with use !important." I have to disagree. What if you want to add like a "highlight on hover" type class during hover. the background would never change. You don't have to use `!important`, you can just simply make a direct reference like `#myelementID .myClassContainer .ui-widget` and get the same "override" result **without** the set back of a "permanent" change.

Comment: This works for me except my dialog has jqueryUI datepicker within it .. which gets painted with the same backgrounds (and almost disappears - apart from the numbers) .. not sure how to get round it

Answer (score 20):

Use the css classes:

- **ui-dialog**

  - Main container of whole thing
- **ui-dialog-title**

  - This is where the title actually appears
- **ui-dialog-titlebar**

  - Area where title of dialog would be if exist
- **ui-dialog-content**

  - Area where your div is actually loaded
- **ui-resizable-handle**

  - These divs are used to resize the dialog but are usually invisble according to your setup
- **ui-dialog-buttonpane**

  - Here is where buttons would go if exist
- **ui-dialog-buttonset**

  - This is where the buttons actually appear

Also, unlike answer given selected, take note, **YOU DON'T HAVE TO USE `!important`**.

If you want a direct call, set everything up and create your dialog. Load the page in Chrome or FF (chrome easier to read). Then simply open the dialog and select the element you want to change. Look at its CSS in your [Browser's Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124974/what-features-does-firebug-have-that-chromes-developer-tools-does-not-have). You'll be able to see the *exact* line jqueryui uses to make it's css call. Simply copy that line into your own CSS and ensure it's loaded later and your dialog will get the new overwrite.

Comment: Old thread, but I just wanted to thank SpYk3HH for the simple list of things that make the life of this noob much easier. Thanks!

Comment: @TimSPQR Just doing what I can to help and give back, as this site and a couple others helped bring me a long way from my old DOS and PERL days

Comment: This solution won't work from a style sheet or style block as only ui-dialog-content will reside in the defined DIV block.  
#myelementID.ui-dialog-content will work, all others are outside your DIV, so they must be accessed in some other fashion.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to target a specific dialog you can do it this way:

```
$('#yourDialog').dialog(
{
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(e) {
        $(e.target).parent().css('background-color','orangered');
    }
});
```

Comment: Or simply: $("#dialogId").css("background-color", "ColorName or Code");

Answer (score 3):

Use this class in css

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    border: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    background: #ff0000;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that you could also go and make your own custom CSS using this link in jQuery

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

jQuery allows us to make a custom-css. Please select the theme you would want from the gallery and hit the edit button, you will be able to change almost everything about the dialog box, as well as the rounded corners.

You then need to download the entire jQuery pack within it you will find css/custom-css folder just put in your css  tag and it will be all sorted basically.

The above ways are also true as you will be able to change it but you will have to look for the classes and stuff like that in the CSS well jQuery does that for us in an easy way and it worked for me as well so you can try it too.

What I basically do is create two to three custom style sheets and then load them up and play with them and finally choose one for the website and discard the rest.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

*your_stylesheet.css*

```
.ui-widget-content { background: yellow; }
```

Make sure your stylesheet is included after the JQuery UI stylesheet, e.g.

*your_webpage.html*

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="your_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

## Long answer

To determine which class and style to override, you will need to inspect a tooltip. Show the tooltip:

```
$("#selector_for_item_with_tooltip").tooltip('open')
```

Right-click on the tooltip and choose "inspect". Scroll down in the "Styles" tab until you find the attribute you care about (`background-color`).

[image: tooltip css styles]

You can click on the value and type in a new value to verify that it will have the effect you desire.

[image: change css style in browser]

To see the format you will need to use to override the format, click on the filename:line # on the upper-right to go to the .css file that defines the attribute (`jquery-ui.css:802`)

[image: jquery-ui css background style]

The format will be

```
.ui-widget-content
{
    background: yellow;
}
```

Your `.css` file needs to use the same style and be included after this one (see "short answer", above).

People sometimes incorrectly add `!important` css suffix to bypass this requirement but that causes all kinds of other headaches.