# Is that possible to set background color property for jQuery dialog's title during its initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm opening error `jQuery` dialog and want to set its title's background to red.
All I saw so far is that I will have to create a `class` for `div` defining my `dialog` and set its background in `css` to red, but, if I do not want to modify existing `.css` file and create another `.css` in my project?

Can I do it in `jQuery's` dialog initialization phase?

For example, I have a `button` `click event`:

```
$("#btnStartSynch").button().unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
    var selectedValue = $("#ddlSynchParam").val();
    if (selectedValue == 0) {
        window.UserSelectMessage.dialog('open');
        return false;
    }

    var userName = $("#ddlSynchParam :selected").text();
    myself.StartSynch(userName, selectedValue);

});
```

If nothing is selected, I open `Error` pop up:

```
window.UserSelectMessage = $("#selectMsg").dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    title: 'Error'
});
```

Can I add extra parameter in that dialog initialization phase to set its background to `red`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268593/jquery-set-modal-dialog-overlay-color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389952/how-to-change-background-color-of-jquery-ui-dialog