# LargeCommandLine Firebug console in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, console, firebug

I find Firebug's "LargeCommandLine" console option very convenient in some cases when you need to play with large pieces of code. Is there some way to have that **exactly the same** functionality in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Try CTRL-SHIFT-J - it is not EXACTLY the same as you demand, but programmed closely resembling  firebug. You cannot get "exactly" the same, since that would mean running firebug itself, and that demands a Firefox infrastructure around it. You could include firefox-light into your page.

Also, you should have searched before posting:
[Firebug-like debugger for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308125/firebug-like-debugger-for-google-chrome)
(scratch that - checked that Q from 2008 - seems like it's perfectly okay to ask again now)

HELP: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html

More Qs here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965/how-do-i-use-the-javascript-console-in-google-chrome
[Firebug for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095352/firebug-for-chrom)

Comment: I wasn't asking about the whole firebug functionality, but only about "LargeCommandLine" option of it. That means: 1) splitted input & output in console; 2) input is not cleared on submit. That's all I need to be happy :)

Comment: Use the "console" tab of the above. THAT part is much better than firebug - no split, just a large console area for input AND output, like any normal console. If you insist on that split of input/output than the answer to your Q is NO, but I wouldn't understand why anyone would prefer the split over a *real* console :)