# Querying A Server And Receiving XML Responses In PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I'm trying to write an API for a website, whose Flash app gets data from a server and presents it to the user. I've been told that I can "have a look web trafic you will the responses from the server are all just basic xml".

This might be the wrong question to ask but, I'm not entirely sure what I've been told to do here. Can I simply use PHP to open the page with the Flash app on, and intercept the XML responses being sent to it? How might that happen?

Alternatively, am I coming at this the wrong way? Do I need to instead know what server the Flash app is accessing, and then open up a connection to that?

This feels like a bad SO question, but I'm at a complete loss. The advice I was given was quite vague so I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the server response in the web traffic, just use the "Net" tab of the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin of firefox.

It should display the request of the flash app with the response from the server which should be in XML.

---

EDIT

You will also know with firebug from which URL the response is coming from and you can then mimic the request of the flash app with your own php script.

Comment: Top stuff! I'll try this out. Do you know of any equivalent for the Chrome browser? I'll google myself too.

Comment: Thanks! That completely made my day, I can move on now. You're a star.

Comment: You can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308125/firebug-like-debugger-for-google-chrome